# How is "context" variable getting the data without applying query-set to it?

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from restaurants.models import Restaurant

class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context)
        print(kwargs)
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^restaurants/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', RestaurantDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

Here, how is "context" variable getting the values from queryset corresponding to the key "pk" that is receives in "kwargs"?

Comment: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/